# Sharedpreferences not saving data when app restart

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make "add favorites" button in my app. I can send and get value with `sharedpreferences` properly, but when I restart the app, favorites are empty again. I guess I need override `OnPause` method, but I couldn't apply properly. I need help, thanks in advance.

**PLAYING RADIO FRAGMENT**

```
public static int incrementedValue = 0;

add_favorites_button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_favorites_button);
        add_favorites_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                editor.putString("radio_link"+ incrementedValue, radio_play_link);
                editor.putString("radio_name" + incrementedValue, radio_name);
                editor.putString("listener_number" + incrementedValue, listener_number);
                //editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

                incrementedValue++;
            }

        });
```

**FAVORITES FRAGMENT**

```
final List<String> radio_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> radio_link_list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> listener_numbers = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i=0; i<PlayRadioFragment.incrementedValue; i++) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
            radio_name_list.add(settings.getString("radio_name" +i, ""));
            radio_link_list.add(settings.getString("radio_link" +i, ""));
            listener_numbers.add(settings.getString("listener_number" +i, ""));
        }
```

...
then I show them in listview
...

Comment: what are you doing on restarting the app?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Shortly, I'm trying to say; when I close the app, favorites are gone.

Comment: what is this variable doing? how are you initializing this?  incrementedValue

Comment: I edited my question, it is for save more than one value in favorites, if I don't put it, editor.putString send value with just one key, and value overwrite itself again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<PlayRadioFragment.incrementedValue; i++)
```

After restarting the app (or Fragment), this `incrementedValue` will be back to what it was initialized with, probably 0, so you won't load anything from `SharedPreferences` (not entering the for-loop at all).

Try something like

```
for (int i=0; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {

   String s = settings.getString("radio_name" +i, "")

   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
      break; 
   } else {
      radio_name_list.add(s); 
   }
```

You probably also want to avoid overwriting the old favorites after the app restart, so you have to set the `incrementedValue` after loading the favorites like

```
incrementedValue = radio_name_list.size();
```

Comment: You're great! Really thank you, it worked. But this time, when I restart the app,if I want to add a new favorite radio, it is overwriting on listview's first item:(

Comment: @PinkRabbits I have edited my question, you have to update your incrementedValue to the size of the list to "start where you left off" so to speak.

Comment: thank you twice, actually it was so simple, It is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because on restarting app the variable named incrementedValue gets value once again as 0 and in for loop conditional statement is not full filling and that's why loop is not executing as expected. To resolve this issue you can do one more thing you need to save the value of incrementedValue  in shared preference as well  and in for loop testing statement get the updated value from shared preference. Hope that helps you